# Installing gfortran 4.6 in Fedora 19

Tags: gcc, gfortran

I am a beginner to Fedora. I use Gamess software programme which requires gfortran 4.6. But when I do "yum install gcc-gfortran", Fedora 19 ships gfortran 4.8.ix my probl

Can anyone tell me in detail to fix my problem.

Comment: Did you try `yum install gcc-gfortran-4.6` (you'd need to uninstall 4.8 first)?

Comment: And are you sure Gamess won't work with gfortran 4.8?

Comment: I uninstalled 4.8 and tried yum install gcc-gfortran-4.6, but no package was available. Also, gamess only take gfortran 4.6 or any other older versions, but not above it.

Answer (score 0):

`gfortran 4.6` has been replaced by a newer version since Fedora 18. You can download prebuilt release. [There](http://gfortran.com/download/x86_64/snapshots/) if you have a 64 bit machine, and [there](http://gfortran.com/download/i686/snapshots/) if you have 32 bit.

Simply unpack it and copy to a directory in your `path`.

Comment: I could unpack it, But, can you please tell me in which path the directory should be. And how to install it.